# Error related to datastage master

Tags: datastage

I created a server job which is supplied from an oracle table
the job is related to a Master. When launching the master, it abort with the following error message "Abnormal termination ", I found a trick to solve the problem, recompling the job before launching the master was the solution.
I'd like to solve this issue, any help will be appreciated 
Thank you

Comment: Sounds strange but the information provided is not sufficient - please add more details like content and the exact error. Is it a Sequence what you call "Master" ?

Comment: the Master is a server job acting as a Sequence, it contains a basic code on job control panel. The job is composed with oracle connector, two consecutive transformers and a sequential file, the error message is "Abnormal termination of stage Generation_fic_commande_1.PLATINIUM.Tr_copy detected"

Comment: Sound to me that your job cannot run twice. What stage or part  is Generation_fic_commande_1.PLATINIUM.Tr_copy ?

Comment: Transformer stage